# Microsoft Word Find/Replace: How to replace brackets surrounding numbers with HTML superscript tags?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I am trying to figure out how to do two related actions using find and replace in Microsoft Word:

1. Replace numbers surrounded by brackets with those same numbers surrounded by superscript HTML tags.

   Example: replace [1] with <sup>1</sup>, [2] with <sup>2</sup>, [3] with <sup>3</sup>, and so on.
2. Replace numbers surrounded by brackets *and preceded by a caret symbol* with those same numbers surrounded by superscript HTML tags.

   Example: replace [^1] with <sup>1</sup>, [^2] with <sup>2</sup>, [^3] with <sup>3</sup>, and so on.

What is the best way to do these two actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1**

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what:`\[([0-9]{1,})\]`
- Press <kbd>More</kbd>. With your cursor in the Find what box, select `Use wilcards`
- Replace with: `<sup>\1</sup>`
- Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

**Part 2**

Same as Part 1 execept for Find what which changes to `\[^^([0-9]{1,})\]`.

[image]